# How/what little food they have!

Tags: grammar

> **How/what** little food they have! They suffer from malnutrition because they eat little food.
>
> **How/what** few books she has! She knows so little because she reads few books.

I wonder whether to use **how or what** in these two sentences.

I guess both work: **What little food they have! = How little food they have!** Just like, **What a beautiful girl she is! = How beautiful a girl she is!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Little*** and ***few*** are [quantifiers](https://www.myenglishpages.com/english/grammar-lesson-quantifiers.php#:%7E:text=A%20quantifier%20is%20a%20word,both%20countable%20and%20uncountable%20nouns.). Now

> Quantifiers are adjectives and adjectival phrases that give approximate or specific answers to the questions "***How*** much?" and "***How*** many?" ([Source](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/quantifiers/))

Among the meanings of the adverb ***how***, [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/how?q=How) mentions:

> to what amount or degree

[What](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/what) is never used for quantities or amounts. In exclamations it is rather used to express emotions or opinions about ***qualities***, as in

> ***What*** a little house they have!

Note that ***what*** is used as a determiner before a Noun Phrase (Adj+Noun), and it requires the article *a/an* before the adjective:

> We can use *what* in exclamations to express a strong feeling or opinion. In this case, we use what as a determiner before a noun or ***before a/an (+ adjective) + noun*** ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/what))

Comment: Careful.  You **need** to use "what little" for quantities or amounts, as: (Correct:) "The people on the island ate **what little food they had**".     (Incorrect:) *"The people ate how little food they had."*

Comment: @whiskeychief Not in exclamations though... In your sentence "what" means "whatever", it does not enhance quantity.

Comment: @fev Hi, I still don't know which to choose in my two sentences where I deliberately distinguished "a little" and "little", "a few" and "few".